# Clean bindings with structs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, struct, cocoa-bindings

I have a model class for which it makes quite a lot of sense to have NSSize and NSPoint instance variables. This is lovely.

I'm trying to create an editing interface for this object. I'd like to bind to `size.width` and whatnot. This, of course, doesn't work.

What's the cleanest, most Cocoa-y solution to this problem? Of course I *could* write separate accessors for the individual members of every struct I use, but it seems like there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create seperate accessors for all the members, you could just create wrappers for the types you care about, e.g.:

```
@interface SizeWrapper : NSObject {
    CGFloat width, height;
}    
@property (readwrite) CGFloat width, height;    
- (id)initWithSize:(NSSize)sz;    
- (NSSize)sizeValue;
@end

@implementation SizeWrapper
@synthesize width, height;

- (id)initWithSize:(NSSize)sz {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        width  = sz.width;
        height = sz.height;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSSize)sizeValue {
    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}
@end
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I'm not sure how to apply it to binding a text field. Wouldn't I still need to write accessors?

Comment: @andyvn22: Removed that part as there would be still some work left.

Comment: This still upsets me (why have CGFloat then!?) but I suppose it will do.

Comment: @alex: It's rather straight-forward - added it it above.